# Bookdown/thesisdown/huskydown: change page margins for a single page within a document

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I have a `huskydown` document (which is based on `thesisdown`/`bookdown`) written in Rmarkdown which is knitted to PDF/LaTex but later also to HTML.

For a single page within the document, I would like to change the page margins (e.g. to include a very large table/figure/external PDF).
After this page, the page margins should return to their default values.

#### What I tried:

````
---
author: 'Your R. Name'
date: 'May 20xx'
institution: 'Reed College'
division: 'Mathematics and Natural Sciences'
advisor: 'Advisor F. Name'
# If you have more two advisors, un-silence line 7
#altadvisor: 'Your Other Advisor'
department: 'Mathematics'
degree: 'Bachelor of Arts'
title: 'My Final College Paper'
knit: "bookdown::render_book"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: 
 thesisdown::thesis_pdf: default
---

### Normal page margins again
```{r echo=FALSE, out.width = '100%'}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + 
  geom_point()
```

\newpage
### Reduced page margins
```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
cat("\\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}")
```

```{r echo=FALSE, out.width = '100%'}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + 
  geom_point()
```

```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
cat("\\restoregeometry")
```

\clearpage
Restore the page margins

### Normal page margins again
```{r echo=FALSE, out.width = '100%'}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + 
  geom_point()
```

# ! Undefined control sequence.
# l.190 \newgeometry
#                   {left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
````

I also tried

```
\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
<!-- material for this page -->
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
```

as suggested by @bretauv. It works in a simple Rmd file, but not in my use case with `huskydown`. I ended up with the same error message.

Comment: Hi, did you check [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78278/how-to-set-page-geometry-for-a-single-page-only)?

Comment: @bretauv Thank you for the link and your suggestion! For me, the fix only works in a simple Rmd file, but not in the thesisdown/bookdown/huskydown. Will update my Q accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hinted by @bretauv in the comment to your question, this issue isn't really coming from rmarkdown or bookdown. It's a *LaTeX* error which is easily solved.

**Background**

As you seem to know, commands from the geometry package can be used to adjust the layout (i.e. especially the page margins) in [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) documents. Basically, it is possible to use such *LaTeX* commands within *rmarkdown* documents. However, a prerequisite is that the corresponding *LaTeX* package is loaded. This is not the case here, hence the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.190 \newgeometry
```

which states that the command `\newgeometry` couldn't be found.

**Solution**

Packages in *LaTeX* are loaded with the command `\usepackage{<pkg_name>}` in the header. This command cannot simply be used in the rmakdown document, it has to be set in a separate template that tells [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) how to create a *PDF* from the *.Rmd* file in the end. For `huskydown` / `thesisdown` this is the file *template.tex* in the project directory.

Open the file and ensure that the package is loaded by adding right the following line *before* `\begin{document}` and then save the file:

```latex
\usepackage[left=6cm,right=6cm,top=6cm,bottom=6cm]{geometry}
```

This will set some default margins and spacings. I chose some (rather dramatic) values that you can of course adjust to your liking.

Knitting your *.Rmd* should work and you now should see the effects of `\newgeometry{}` or `\restoregeometry`. Also, note that is not necessary to fence these with a code chunk.

**Example**

(using `thesisdown`)

````
### Default (reduced) page margins as defined by geometry    
```{r, echo=FALSE, out.width = '100%'}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point()
```
 
\newpage
 
\newgeometry{left=3cm,top=6cm,right=3cm,bottom=6cm}
 
### Larger margins
 
```{r, echo=FALSE, out.width = '100%'}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point()
```
````

[image]